# Deleted Apache Cache

Tags: apache, webmin

In my attempt of deleting the Magento Cache from folder webmin filemanager I accidently deleted the Apache folder /var/cache/ and all of its subfolders instead.

Now with my very limited knowledge of Apache I am afraid that I have corrupted my webserver.

Should I worry about it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: No, because it is not related to Magento. It is related to Apache.

Comment: Why tag with Magento if it's not about Magento? It's still not about programming. It should be deleted.

Comment: Ok. To get back on track, in the hope that someone will actually relate to the core issue as it is all about I have now deleted "Magento" as a tag.

Comment: The nature of a cache is typically that it gets created as needed. You might have to make the folder again and give Apache read/write permissions, though.

Comment: @TheDenster - This is still not about programming. This is a programming-related site. This should be on http://serverfault.com/.

Comment: @Enigmativity As someone with a decent chunk of SF rep, no, this shouldn't be on ServerFault. (You're right that it shouldn't be on SO, though.) Questions regarding servers with control panels like Webmin are explicitly off-topic on SF.

Comment: @ceejayoz - Thanks for the clarification.